# has_many / belongs_to validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, has-many

Consider the following code

```
class CreateFoosAndBars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
    create_table :bars do |t|
      t.integer :foo_id
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  validates_presence_of :foo
end
```

So, foos can have any number of bars and bars cannot exist without a foo.

This code should save, but it doesn't:

```
irb(main):020:0> foo = Foo.new
=> #<Foo id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):021:0> foo.bars.build
=> #<Bar id: nil, foo_id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):022:0> foo.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
=> false
irb(main):023:0> foo.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fb325b35e68 @base=#<Foo id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:bars=>["er ikke gyldig"]}>
irb(main):024:0>
```

I am using Rails 4.0.3 for this project.

I can't seem to grasp how to transactionally initialize, validate and save a foo with a number of bars. What am I missing here?

Comment: The thing is, it is not blank. The foo exists, but it's not persisted yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work, I copy pasted your example into a new rails app:

```
class CreateFoosAndBars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
    create_table :bars do |t|
      t.integer :foo_id
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  validates_presence_of :foo
end
```

And these were the results:

```
2.1.1 :001 > Foo.count
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "foos"
 => 0
2.1.1 :002 > Bar.count
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "bars"
 => 0
2.1.1 :003 > foo = Foo.new
 => #<Foo id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
2.1.1 :004 > foo.bars.build
 => #<Bar id: nil, foo_id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
2.1.1 :005 > foo.save
   (0.3ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "foos" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-06-21 16:24:15.334535"], ["updated_at", "2014-06-21 16:24:15.334535"]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "bars" ("created_at", "foo_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-06-21 16:24:15.342524"], ["foo_id", 1], ["updated_at", "2014-06-21 16:24:15.342524"]]
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 => true
2.1.1 :006 > foo.errors
 => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007ff37b9514a8 @base=#<Foo id: 1, name: nil, created_at: "2014-06-21 16:24:15", updated_at: "2014-06-21 16:24:15">, @messages={}>
2.1.1 :007 > Foo.count
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "foos"
 => 1
2.1.1 :008 > Bar.count
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "bars"
 => 1
```

This is using Rails 4.1.0.

In versions of Rails prior to 4.1.0, you would have to specify the following relationship:

```
class Foo
  has_many :bars, inverse_of: :foo
end
```

However Rails 4.1.0 now heuristically detects inverse associations as documented [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/10886/files).

Comment: You are right. It seems OP has extra validation - *@messages={:bars=>["er ikke gyldig"]}>*.. And it is on `Bar` model.

Comment: I have a "validates_presence_of :foo" on Bar, which is causing the issue.

Comment: I have a `validates_presence_of :foo` on Bar as well, it's not an issue when I run the code.

Comment: I have just created a 4.1.1 test app and cannot reproduce the 'bug'. :)

Comment: That's, interesting, I'm curious as to when this was fixed.

Comment: Yes you're right, automatic detecting of inverse relationships was only added in 4.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = Foo.build
bar = foo.bars.build
bar.save
```

The reason being you are creating bars without saving foo. Hence foo is invalid. You must save foo before that, so it can get an id.

Update:

You have to use inverse_of in your in your bar model.

```
belongs_to :foo, inverse_of :bar
```

Foo model

```
has_many :bards, inverse_of :foo
```

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: But I want to do it transactionally. They are mutually dependent on each other. And I need to correct myself. A foo should not be saved unless its bars are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the inverse_of option to both of your associations. Maybe Rails is getting confused somewhere and can't match them up.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the solution.

If I do this

```
foo = Foo.new
bar = foo.bars.build
bar.foo
=> nil
```

So `build` is lying. It's not building a bar associated with foo as you would expect. `build` only works when the foo is persisted.

However, if I add `inverse_of: :foo` to my Foo models association, like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars, inverse_of: :foo
end
```

It suddenly oddly works. Calling `foo` on the built bar instance suddenly returns an object instead of nil.

```
irb(main):002:0> bar = foo.bars.build
=> #<Bar id: nil, foo_id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):003:0> bar.foo
=> #<Foo id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):005:0> bar.foo.object_id
=> 70208007135620
irb(main):006:0> foo.object_id
=> 70208007135620
```

I do not know why this is neccessary and not the default behavior.

### Update

This issue only applies to Rails versions older than 4.1.0.

Comment: you should submit a bug report to the rails project if there isn't already one covering this issue